# Use of SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a SQL table (simplified) containing 4 columns as you can see in this picture

[image]

When the state of a demand will become "Done" I want its Priority to be null and all demands with above priorities decremented.

For example, if  the second demand : "Bread" is "Done", its priority will be set to null and I want "Butter" to have a priority of 2, and "Jam"  a priority of 3.

Do I need a trigger ? And if so (Engine : InnoDB) , could I have some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a trigger for that.

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER modify_priority_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
    if NEW.priority = 'Done'
    then
       update your_table
       set priority = priority - 1
       where priority is not null
       and priority > NEW.priority;

       set NEW.priority = NULL;
    end if;
end
|
delimiter ;
```

The trigger above is fired on updates of your table. First it decrements the priority of the other records and then it sets the current priority to null.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I just correct  a line :
    if NEW.State= 'Done'


But I have an error in MySQL : MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

I look at this error on the Internet, and it's a kind of "infinite loop" but I can't find how to correct it.

Comment: You can ask another question about that specific problem on Stack Overflow